# Loop to append data to sql database depending on user input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

- My database is set up with potentially 6 different products.
- The user determines the number of products
- I want to display the database data
  depending on how many products are listed in there (It is coded to
  accommodate up to 6)
- I am stuck on how to make a loop depending on this

***This code calls the data in database:***

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid=$productid;";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<b>Event name: </b>";
                    echo "";
                    echo $row['1_name'];
                    echo "<p></p> ";
                    echo "<b>Event Venue: </b>";
                    echo " ";
                    echo $row['1_price'];
                    echo " <p></p>";
                    echo "<b>Event Date: </b>";
                    echo " ";
                    echo $row['1_quantity'];
                    echo " <p></p>";
                    ?>
```

***SQL DATABASE:***

```
    1_name varchar(256),
    1_price int(11),
    1_quantity int(11),

    2_name varchar(256),
    2_price int(11),
    2_quantity int(11),

    3_name varchar(256),
    3_price int(11),
    3_quantity int(11),

    4_name varchar(256),
    4_price int(11),
    4_quantity int(11),


    5_name varchar(256),
    5_price int(11),
    5_quantity int(11),

    6_name varchar(256),
    6_price int(11),
    6_quantity int(11),

    7_name varchar(256),
    7_price int(11),
    7_quantity int(11)





);
```

Answer (score 0):

- To view all products data change your query from

  `"SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid=$productid"`

  to

  `"SELECT * FROM products"`
- To limit the products based on user's input use this query

  `"SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $limit"`

  the said query will get nth number of products depending on the set `$limit`
- If you want to view the latest products and still set limit you could use this query

  `"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productid DESC LIMIT $limit"`

Comment: Hello, How do I echo all the other products from the database so I can limit them ? After that I think your advice will work